# String disappearing from C++ code to Lua script

Tags: lua, cryengine

I am completely new to CryEngine and Lua scripting, so forgive me if I am missing something painfully obvious.

I am attempting to pass a command from a Flash animation to a Lua script. The script will, in turn, call another Flash animation to display in the main window.  The process worked fine in one scenario, but we are trying to move it to a more general solution.  (This is creating a myriad of other problems, but they aren't relevant here.)

What's working fine is: using the command sent from the flash actionscript to call the proper C++ function.  Also, when called directly, the Lua script is properly using the command to call the second Flash animation and display it.

The problem lies in the middle.

```
void HUD::AlternateCommand(const char* command)
{
   // Code to select the proper Lua script and function
   Script::Call(ss, ssf, command);
}
```

This is supposed to pass the command to the Lua script.  However, when the string reaches the script, it is suddenly nil.  I have absolutely no clue why this is happening, especially since other similar commands have been properly passed through.

Any ideas?

Comment: I did a work around so that a function in the Lua script corresponds to the command name.  Not the best solution, but it works for what I need it to do now.